# Next N elements for a Iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

```
def infinite_generator():
    i = 0

    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i
```

I have a generator function which looks a like this.

```
def first_second_and_fifty_items():

    iterator = iter(infinite_generator())

    first = next(iterator)
    second = next(iterator)
    next_fifty = [next(iterator) for _ in range(50)]

    return first, second, next_fifty
```

And I have a second function which looks a little like this.

Is there a better way to take elements from the iterator?

Comment: The only [functional] problem with your code is the unnecessary call to *iter()*

Comment: just don't use `iter` but `list` directly. `x, y, *z = list(my_iterator); return x, y, z`

Comment: @cards the generator here is infinite, so `list(infinite_generator())` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.islice`, it is a more flexible approach

```
from itertools import islice

def first_second_and_fifty_items():
    iterator = infinite_generator()

    first = next(iterator)
    second = next(iterator)
    next_fifty = list(islice(iterator, 50))

    return first, second, next_fifty
```

Comment: Removal of the unnecessary call to *iter()* is good but the use of *islice()* is overkill when a simple list comprehension will suffice

Comment: `return *islice(iterator, 2), list(islice(iterator, 50))`

Answer (score 1):

using `iter` property and order of execution in python

you can achive this as

```
>>> def first_second_and_fifty_items():
...     itera = infinite_generator()
...     return next(itera), next(itera), [next(itera) for _ in range(50)]
...
>>> first_second_and_fifty_items()
(1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you consider better. I myself would prefer only specifying how many new elements you want from your iterator. E.g.:

```
start = 0
class InfIter:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.start = 0
        self.x = start

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        global start
        if self.x >= self.limit+start:
            start = self.x
            raise StopIteration

        self.x += 1
        return self.x
```

This will give you similar results to your example in the form of lists with however many elements you want.

```
print(list(InfIter(1)), list(InfIter(1)), list(InfIter(50)))
```

This would evaluate to

```
[1] [2] [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired result. Also, why *global start* ?

Comment: If there is no gobal start variable this solution would always re-start counting from 1. I also just realised that the self.start=0 is an artifact of my first attempt. It should not remain.